# How to do packet mangling with winsock2 in windows?

Tags: windows, winsock2

I'm following examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740632%28v=VS.85%29.aspx),

but none of them provides an example on how to **modify** packets(previously I used winpcap only to found that it can ONLY read packets!).

Can someone give me some clue even which function can actually **modify** incoming/outgoing packets??

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a custom NDIS driver or use existing solutions like WinpkFilter. There are no built-in function in Windows to modify packets in the user land.